# Redirect user when error occurs in async controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asynchronous, task

I have an ***ASP.NET MVC 4*** web application that retrieves data from a data source via WCF services.

I have set up most of controllers to be `Async` and subsequent methods to be `Task` based.

I have encountered a problem though. If an exception occurs in my code, the page being loaded just continues to load and in the end times-out with the IIS error page showing.

I have a friendly error message set up and works fine for `sync` actions but not `async` ones. The action just keeps running even though an exception may have occurred at a different level. I tried applying the `AsyncTimeout` attribute to the controller action but no luck, page just keeps loading for a long period of time.

Any ideas how I could handle this in my code, preferably at a global type level and direct the user to an error page when an issue occurs with an `async` controller action?

Answer (score 4):

### Approach #1

**Set customErrors to On or RemoteOnly in Web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

**Use HandleErrorAttribute with custom error view**

```
[AsyncTimeout(1000)]
[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(System.TimeoutException), View="Timeout")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncActionResultReport()
{
```

---

### Approach #2

**Override the OnException Method of your Async Controller, or use a custom Exception Attribute**

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if(filterContext.Exception is TimeoutException && filterContext.Controller is AsyncController)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Home" },
                    { "Action", "TimeoutRedirect" }
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do controller level, the `HandleError` as suggested by Dave A is perfect. But for applying **HandleError Attribute at Global Level** you have to use **ExceptionFilter**.

You can also apply the `HandleError` Attribute for the entire application by registering it as a global error handler. For registering a global error handler, open the `FilterConfig.cs` file with in `App_Start` folder to find the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method.
By default, ASP.NET MVC template has already registered a global `HandleErrorAttribute` to the `GlobalFilterCollection` for your application. Here you can also add your own custom filter to the global filter collection as well like :

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
  {
    ExceptionType = typeof(System.TimeoutException),
    View = "TimeoutExceptionView"
  });

  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); //by default added
}
```

For details refer:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/19D9140313-Exception-or-Error-Handling-and-Logging-in-MVC4.html

**OR**

**Alternatively** you can use `Application_Error`(NOT Recommended) to catch exception & redirect to required action like:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);
    if (exc.GetType() == typeof(TimeoutException)
    {
      Response.Redirect("/Home/ErrorView");
    }
}
```